# the firebaseError error message display when trying to create new collection called message inside channelroom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field user in document channelroom/mfJm8DH7f5w14GO1W45y

the firebaseError error message display when trying to create new collection called message inside channelroom/mfJm8DH7f5w14GO1W45y/messages
/6lUXO2mRwl75G0hV3HoA)

```
    import React,{useState,useContext} from 'react';
import db from './firebase';
import {AuthContext} from './StateProvider';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const ChatIput = ({channelName,roomId}) => {
    
    const [input,setInput] = useState("");
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

        const sendMessage = (e) =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            if(roomId){ 
                db.collection("channelroom")
                .doc(roomId).collection("messages")
                .add({
                    post:input,
                    user:currentUser.displayName,
                    userImg:currentUser.photoURL,
                    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                });
            }
            setInput("");
        }

    return(
            <div className="chat_input">
                <form>
                    <input value={input}
                     onChange={(e)=>setInput(e.target.value)}
                     placeholder={`message ${channelName}`}/>
                    <button type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
    )
}
```

export default ChatIput;

Comment: Please, instead of copying/pasting a screenshot of your IDE, paste the code as text and format it as code. This way we can copy it in order to write an answer.

Comment: I don't think the error message refers to this code.  It's complaining about at call to `set()`, which you don't have here.  Please find the code with the error, and copy it into the question (don't show a screenshot).

Comment: I have pasted the code, thanks.

Comment: You are still not showing a call to a method called `set()` anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `currentUser.displayName` and not `currentUser.dispayName`.

```
// ...
.add({
  post: input,
  user: currentUser.displayName,
  // ...
 })
```